# Implementation of `diesel::query_builder::Query` is not general enough error

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I have a MRE repo here: https://github.com/hansl/mre-issue-higher-ranked

Essentially, I'm using a Rocket handler function like so:

```rust
#[get("/")]
async fn index(mut db: Db) -> String {
    let query = schema::posts::table.into_boxed();

    let (items, total): (Vec<models::Post>, i64) = query
        .paginate(Some(0))
        .load_and_count_total(&mut db)
        .await
        .unwrap();

    format!("{items:?} {total}\n")
}
```

I'm defining the `paginate` and `load_and_count_total` functions as follow (in the `pages.rs` module):

```rust
pub trait Paginate: Sized {
    fn paginate(self, page: Option<i64>) -> Paginated<Self>;
}

impl<T: Query> Paginate for T {
    fn paginate(self, page: Option<i64>) -> Paginated<Self> {
        let page = page.unwrap_or(0);

        Paginated {
            query: self,
            per_page: DEFAULT_PER_PAGE,
            page,
            offset: page * DEFAULT_PER_PAGE,
        }
    }
}

// ...

impl<T> Paginated<T> {
    pub async fn load_and_count_total<'a, U>(
        self,
        conn: &mut AsyncPgConnection,
    ) -> QueryResult<(Vec<U>, i64)>
    where
        Self: LoadQuery<'a, AsyncPgConnection, (U, i64)>,
        U: Send,
        T: 'a,
    {
        // Ignore those linting errors. `get(0)` cannot be replaced with `first()`.
        #![allow(clippy::get_first)]

        let results = self.load::<(U, i64)>(conn).await?;
        let total = results.get(0).map(|x| x.1).unwrap_or(0);
        let records = results.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect();
        Ok((records, total))
    }
}
```

The error given while compiling is:

```
error: implementation of `diesel::query_builder::Query` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:1
   |
12 | #[get("/")]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `diesel::query_builder::Query` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `diesel::query_builder::Query` would have to be implemented for the type `BoxedSelectStatement<'0, (Integer, Text), FromClause<table>, Pg>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `diesel::query_builder::Query` is actually implemented for the type `BoxedSelectStatement<'1, (Integer, Text), FromClause<table>, Pg>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `get` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I've tried a lot of various combinations of lifetimes in `load_and_count_total` and specifying or restricting types, I just cannot get this to work. Best I could do is remove the `into_boxed()` which fixes the error, but I need it as the conditions get exponentially complex in my real world original code and I need to be able to conditionally filter my queries.

The actual code is much more complex, but I've tried to lower it to the simplest form of reproduction I could get. All modules except `main.rs` and `pages.rs` can be ignored in the repo.

#### Expected Results

I would expect `load_and_count_total` to work as expected without a compiler error about different lifetimes.

Doing some research leads me to believe this is a compiler error that's been documented in issues that are still opened, but it seems there also might be a solution that doesn't involve fixing the compiler. I just cannot find it for my specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a few days (and hours after playing with the MRE) of investigating this specific issue, I figured a way to tell the compiler that my code is safe.

Instead of declaring `load_and_count_total` as `async`, I changed the declaration to the following:

```rust
impl<T: Query> Paginated<T> {
    pub fn load_and_count_total<'a, U>(
        self,
        conn: &'a mut AsyncPgConnection,
    ) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = QueryResult<(Vec<U>, i64)>> + Send + 'a
    where
        Self: LoadQuery<'a, AsyncPgConnection, (U, i64)>,
        U: Send + 'a,
        T: 'a,
    {
        // Ignore those linting errors. `get(0)` cannot be replaced with `first()`.
        #![allow(clippy::get_first)]

        let results = self.load::<(U, i64)>(conn);

        async move {
            let results = results.await?;
            let total = results.get(0).map(|x| x.1).unwrap_or(0);
            let records = results.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect();
            Ok((records, total))
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the extra `+ Send + 'a` limitations on the return type, which let the compiler know that the Future is alive for the whole duration of `'a`, and the `Send`. Seems that both are necessary for the compiler to stop complaining, but neither are actually inferred by the compiler automatically if the function is declared `async`.

This fixes the issue above.